# How to format bash SED/AWK/Per output for further processing

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have some text file data that I am parsing with SED, AWK and Perl.

```
product {
    name { thing1 }
    customers {        
        mary { }
        freddy { }
        bob {
            spouse betty
        }
    }
}
```

From the "customers" section, I am trying to get output similar to:

```
mary{ }
freddy{ }
bob{spouse betty}
```

Using: `sed -n -e "/customers {/,/}/{/customers {/d;/}/d;p;}" $file'`

This is the output:

```
mary { }
freddy { }
bob {
    spouse betty
}
```

How can I concatenate the "bob" customer to one line and remove the extra spaces? The main reason for this specific output is that I am writing a script to grab the "customer" fields and other fields in the text file, then outputting them to a csv file. Which will look something like this. I know this would probably be easier in another language, but bash is what I know.

```
output.csv
product,customers,another_column
thing1,mary{ } freddy{ } bob{spouse betty},something_else
```

Comment: If I offer an answer using another language, are you willing to do some work to get a little familiar with the language?

Comment: In Perl, you can write a parser for the format (if it doesn't already exist) and do whatever you need with the resulting structures.

Comment: @glennjackman yes, I'm trying to get this wrapped up

Comment: @choroba I'm not familiar with how to do that, but it would probably make this a lot easier.

Comment: Where the input data originated from? Is there a possibility to get output at source in [json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [yaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) format? If the answer is no, then it would require to _crank out_ a parser to accommodate this input format.

Comment: @PolarBear Unfortunately not, the data is what it is. In the larger scheme, there are about 50 profile types and I am trying to NOT have to write parsers for each one, but this is a common data structure among the profiles so I am just trying to find an expedient method to deal with this type of pattern.

Comment: See [this PerlMonks reply](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11147105) for an example of a similar format + parser.

Comment: @glennjackman Thinking tcl?

Comment: What are possible variations on this format?  How many sub-records (like `spouse betty`...) can there be, and are they each on a line of their own? Does `customers` section always (_always_) ends with a solitary `}` on a line? ...

Comment: @Shawn, you know me well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data happens to have valid [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) list syntax:

```
set f [open "input.file"]
set data [dict create {*}[read $f]]
close $f

set name [string trim [dict get $data product name]]
dict for {key val} [dict get $data product customers] {
    lappend customers [format "%s{%s}" $key [string trim $val]]
}

set f [open "output.csv" w]
puts $f "product,customers,another_column"
puts $f [join [list $name [join $customers] "something_else"] ,]
close $f
```

creates output.csv with

```
product,customers,another_column
thing1,mary{} freddy{} bob{spouse betty},something_else
```

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**   *See end for producing a complete desired output*

---

Here is [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) for it, probably in just about any language, run on the whole file in a string.  This, as it stands, assumes that there can only be one level of nesting under a customer, in other words `bob` cannot have `{ pets { dog } }` or some such.

Extract content of `customers` section

```
/customers\s*{\s* ( (?: [^{]+ {[^}]*} )+ )/x;
```

then collapse newline + spaces into a single space

```
s/\n\s+/ /g;
```

then trim spaces from strings like `bob { spouse }`, but not from `mary { }`

```
s/{\s+ ([^}]+) \s+}/{$1}/gx;
```

If `bob` and the crew can really be only word-characters then instead of `[^{}]` we can use the far nicer `\w`.

Altogether, in a Perl command-line program as seems to be desired

```
perl -wE'die "file?\n" if not @ARGV; 
    $d = do { local $/; <> };
    ($c) = $d =~ /customers\s*{\s* ( (?: [^{]+ {[^}]*} )+ )/x; 
    $c =~ s/\n\s+/ /g;          
    $c =~ s/{\s+ ([^}]+) \s+}/{$1}/gx; 
    say $c
' data.txt
```

This prints, for data given in the question

```
mary { } freddy { } bob {spouse betty}
```

To print each customer on a separate line can do for example

```
say for split /(?<=\})\s+/, $c;
```

(to be the last line in code)

---

I now realize that there is more to capture and print, described in the last paragraph. Adding to the beginning of the regex to capture the `name`, and adding the required printing

```
perl -wE'die "file?\n" if not @ARGV; 
    $d = do { local $/; <> };
    ($n, $c) = $d =~ /name\s*{\s* ([^}]+) \s*} .*?  customers\s*{\s* ( (?: [^{]+ {[^}]*} )+ )/sx; 
    $n =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
    $c =~ s/\n\s+/ /g;
    $c =~ s/{\s+ ([^}]+) \s+}/{$1}/gx; 
    say "product,customers,another_column"
    say "$n,$c,something_else"
' data.txt > output.csv
```

Output redirected to `output.csv` is as shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples Only. In GNU `awk` you could try following `awk` code. We could do it in a single GNU `awk`, we need not to pass your `sed` command's output to any other tool. Just pass your Input_file to this `awk` program(s).

***1st solution:*** To get output between `customers` section to `}` its closing bracket and values not having starting spaces try following GNU `awk` solution.

```bash
awk -v RS='\n[[:space:]]+customers {[[:space:]]*.*\n[[:space:]]+}' '
RT{
  sub(/^\n[[:space:]]+[^ ]* {[[:space:]]*\n/,"",RT)
  sub(/\n[[:space:]]+}/,"",RT)
  match(RT,/(.*{)[[:space:]]*([^\n]*)(.*)/,arr)
  sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",arr[1])
  sub(/\n/,"",arr[2])
  gsub(/\n|^[[:space:]]+/,"",arr[3])
  gsub(/\n[[:space:]]+/,"\n",arr[1])
  gsub(/ {/,"{",arr[1])
  print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
mary{ }
freddy{ }
bob{spouse betty}
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** To have starting spaces before values try following code.

```bash
awk -v RS='\n[[:space:]]+customers {[[:space:]]*.*\n[[:space:]]+}' '
RT{
  sub(/^\n[[:space:]]+[^ ]* {[[:space:]]*\n/,"",RT)
  sub(/\n[[:space:]]+}/,"",RT)
  match(RT,/(.*{)[[:space:]]*([^\n]*)(.*)/,arr)
  sub(/\n/,"",arr[2])
  gsub(/\n|^[[:space:]]+/,"",arr[3])
  print arr[1] arr[2] arr[3]
}
'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
        mary { }
        freddy { }
        bob {spouse betty}
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be in GNU `awk` setting RS(record separator) as `\n[[:space:]]+customers {[[:space:]]*.*\n[[:space:]]+}` to match only required match. Then in main block of this `awk` program remove all unnecessary(not needed strings parts) as per requirement by `sub`(substitute function) and then using `match` function with regex `(.*{)[[:space:]]*([^\n]*)(.*)` with 3 capturing groups whose values are getting stored into an array named `arr` and then I am substituting all newlines/spaces from it and then printing the values of current line with RT for same.

Answer (score 1):

Following code sample demonstrates most primitive parser for provided sample data.

This code restores data structure and can be then used any imaginable way, for example stored as *CVS*, *JSON*, *YAML* file.

In real life the input data can be quite different and this code probably will not process it correctly.

The code provided for educational purpose only.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ s/\n/ /g;
$data =~ s/ +/ /g;

say Dumper parse($data);

exit 0;

sub parse {
    my $str  = shift;   
    my $ret;

    while( $str =~ /^(\S+) \{ (\S+) \{ \S+/ ) {
        if( $str =~ /^(\S+) \{ (\S+) \{ ([^}]+?) \{(.+?)\}/ ) {
            $ret->{$1}{$2}{$3} = $4;
            $ret->{$1}{$2}{$3} =~ s/(^\s+|\s+$)//g;
            $str =~ s/^(\S+) \{ (\S+) \{(.+?)\{(.*?)\}/$1 \{ $2 \{/;
        }
        if( $str =~ /^(\S+) \{ (\S+) \{\s*([^{]+?)\s*\}/ ) {
            $ret->{$1}{$2} = $3 if length($3) > 1;
            $str =~ s/^(\S+) \{ \S+ \{\s*[^\}]+\s*\}/$1 \{/;
        }
    }
    
    return $ret;
}

__DATA__
product {
    name { thing1 }
    customers {        
        mary { }
        freddy { }
        bob {
            spouse betty
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'product' => {
                         'customers' => {
                                          'bob' => 'spouse betty',
                                          'freddy' => '',
                                          'mary' => ''
                                        },
                         'name' => 'thing1'
                       }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `ed`

```
ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  %s/^[[:space:]]*//
  ?{?;/^}/j
  %s/^\([^\{]*\) \(.*\)$/\1\2 /
  /^customers/+1;/^}/-1j
  s/^/thing1,/
  s/ *$/,someting_else/
  p
  Q
EOF
```

---

With a temp file, it is a bit more easier to write to a new file.

```
ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  %s/^[[:space:]]*//
  /customers {/+1;/^[[:space:]]*}/w out.txt
  %d
  r out.txt
  ?{?;/^}/j
  %s/^\([^\{]*\) \(.*\)$/\1\2 /
  %j
  s/^/thing1,/
  s/ *$/,someting_else/
  0a
product,customers,another_column
.
  w output.csv
  ,p
  Q
EOF
```

---

- The latter creates two files, `out.txt` and `output.csv`
- Remove the `,p` if stdout output is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Input file is called "stack" here.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

cat > ed1 <<EOF
/customers/
+1
ka
$
-2
kb
'a,'bW output.txt
q
EOF

ed -s stack < ed1
```